# C# Z Index Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, z-index, windows-forms-designer

How can I set Windows Form z-index?

The second layer first opens, then the first layer. How can I check for this? And how can I change the z-order ranking?

### [image: Layer demonstration]

Comment: What is "x order ranking"? And to be clear, you're asking about controls on a form, and not the form itself, right?

Comment: sorry ı mean z order ranking .

Comment: In the same app, `BringToFront()` works for both child Controls and Forms (for docked Controls, the opposite, you call `SendToBack()` :)